# PCL - range image from synthetic cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library

I cannot seem to be able to get a range image (if I visualize it I just see a black dot/square).

I am using a point cloud I generated, that has around 5K points. Following the instructions at http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/range_image_creation.php and getting the affine matrix from the viewer, after I reset it to look at the cloud, which is positioned at the origin.

Could it be a view position problem?